# Filename instead of stream in custom extractor

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm implementing a custom extractor to read grib files, which is a binary format, and I use a NuGet package called Grib.Api to read the grib files. This API expects a filename when opening a file, and in a USQL custom extractor I only get a stream, so I don't know how to use this package in USQL. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the byte stream into a local file inside your container and then pass that filename to the API.

Also ask the owners of the API to let you pass in a byte stream directly ;).